# How to create a VIEW by join multiple tables having multiple columns using SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, join

I am creating a view for a table and joining multiple tables for additional columns, getting exact output for some join tables which has only two columns(ID, Name) in it. But i am getting 'Ambiguous column error' for a column which i am using  one join table which has more than 10 columns in it.

I know why I am getting this error but i need help to call the `EventName` from `EventInfo` join table. Also is it possible to give different column names in the view.

Below are the select statement and the join table that I am getting error.

Thanks in advance for your suggestions.

```
SELECT 
    Event_ID, EventName 
FROM 
    [dbo].[tbl_ValueTool_Event_ResultantDataEntryData] Res_event      
JOIN 
    [GRID_ProjectServer_Applications].[dbo].[tbl_ValueTool_EventInformation] EVT ON Res_event.[Event_ID] = EVT.[Event_ID]
```

Below is the join table from which I want to call the column names corresponding to the Id's

[image]

Comment: Have you tried `SELECT EVT.Event_ID, EVT.EventName 
   FROM [dbo].[tbl_ValueTool_Event_ResultantDataEntryData] Res_event      
   JOIN [GRID_ProjectServer_Applications].[dbo].[tbl_ValueTool_EventInformation] EVT
   ON Res_event.[Event_ID] = EVT.[Event_ID]`

Comment: Since Event_Id column is present in both the table , so we need to provide the alias and specify exactly from which table the column is referenced

Comment: @RajatMishra - Thank you, yes i got the required result. one more thing can we give different column names instead of having same names in original table to which we are creating view.

Comment: @Virat Use Alias. Example: Evt.Event_ID AS <<New Name>>

Comment: Never mind i tried "EventName AS Event_Name", it works. I appreciate your help and for your time, Thanks once again.

Comment: @DVT thank you sir,

Comment: @Virat please accept the answer if it worked for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use alias for the column names if needed.

```
SELECT EVT.Event_ID, EVT.EventName 
FROM [dbo].[tbl_ValueTool_Event_ResultantDataEntryData] Res_event 
JOIN [GRID_ProjectServer_Applications].[dbo].[tbl_ValueTool_Event‌​Information] EVT 
ON Res_event.[Event_ID] = EVT.[Event_ID]
```